# Why does getenv("QUERY_STRING") return null in a FastCGI C++ program?

Tags: c++, fastcgi, lighttpd

So I have a working FastCGI application written in C++ using Light HTTPd, however I'm unable to retrieve the querystring using `getenv("QUERY_STRING")`. Everything works fine if I take out the querystring request (or add a check for null), but with that in place it fails:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <process.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
extern char ** environ;
#endif

#include "fcgio.h"
#include "fcgi_config.h"  // HAVE_IOSTREAM_WITHASSIGN_STREAMBUF
#include "redisclient.h"
```

....

```
 while (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0)
 {        
    fcgi_streambuf cin_fcgi_streambuf(request.in);
    fcgi_streambuf cout_fcgi_streambuf(request.out);
    fcgi_streambuf cerr_fcgi_streambuf(request.err);
```

...

```
    cout << "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
                "\r\n"
                "<TITLE>^_^</TITLE>\n"
                "<H1>echo-cfpp</H1>\n"
                "<H4>PID: " << pid << "</H4>\n"
                "<H4>Request Number: " << ++count << "</H4>\n";

    // If I make this conditional on getenv("QUERY_STRING") not returning null,
    // then the program behaves reliably.
    cout <<getenv("QUERY_STRING");
 }
```

I've verified that I'm passing a querystring in the request, so why then is getenv("QUERY_STRING") returning null? And what *should* I be doing to retrieve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have extensive experience with the reference FastCGI library for C/C++, but I've implemented both CGI and FastCGI libraries for Windows in the past, so the following might help.

Basically, as per [the FastCGI specification](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html), the CGI environment variables are passed through the `FCGI_PARAMS` stream, which are normally decoded by the FastCGI library.  Now, FastCGI doesn't specify much about what is required and what isn't, and it's assumed that the rules are *basically the same as for CGI*.  The CGI specification section 4.1.7 says the following about the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable:

> The server **MUST** set this variable; if the `Script-URI` does not include a query component, the `QUERY_STRING` **MUST** be defined as an empty string (`""`).

Now, this basically means that your FastCGI library is decoding a `QUERY_STRING` parameter in the `FCGI_PARAMS` stream (or else the gateway server is not following the specification).

Since the reference library tries to abstract both CGI and FastCGI library in the same program and supports multi-threading, I strongly doubt that you would find the result in an environment variable (or there would be a race condition).

Basically, this means [`getenv()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/getenv/) always returns `NULL` and you are passing a null `const char*` to an `std::ostream` through `operator<<` is illegal.  This probably crashes your application since `NULL` is not a special value designating the end of stream.

---

**TL; DR**:
You cannot access the `QUERY_STRING` value through the process environment *because you are using FastCGI, not CGI*.  You need to read the library's documentation for the standard way to access the request's query string.

---

**Edit**: I've got some more info on this situation.

The [documentation for `FCGX_Accept_r()` in `fcgiapp.h`](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/include/fcgiapp.h) says`:

> Creates a parameters data structure to be accessed
>   via `getenv(3)` (**if assigned to `environ`**) or by `FCGX_GetParam`
>   and assigns it to `*envp`.

Using the following after `FCGX_Accept_r` would fix the issue:

```
environ = request.envp;
```

However, this is not safe for multi-threaded applications (`environ` is not in thread-local storage), so I recommend that you use the other documented method instead:

```
const char * query_string = FCGX_GetParam("QUERY_STRING", request.envp);
```

Comment: this is actually the libraries documented way of accessing query string, sadly. http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fastcgi-prog-guide/ch2c.htm I rtfm'd a lot before i came here. Also I found out about null thanks for affirming that.

Comment: @user1202909: Updated my answer.  Your code does not satisfy the pre-conditions stated in the documentation.

Comment: Actually, FWIW, libstdc++ checks for streaming of null `char const*`. It's still UB, of course

Comment: The documentation is so sparse i'm not even sure where you found that but thanks for the link and info. You should really have concentrated on this instead of asking me for irrelevant stuff. The information i gave out was obviously sufficient if you were able to find the answer.

Comment: @user1202909: I found it by reading the documentation on the first Google hit.  And what I asked is not irrelevant.  My answer was a **guess** because I didn't know if **your** program used `environ=request.envp;` or not.  If you had show me your code, I would have found your answer faster and could have given you a **reliable, straightforward, 2-line answer**.

Comment: @user1202909: You know... you asked a question, we tried to help and asked for more information, and all you've done is *fight back* (first by resisting, then by insulting).  And how that I've solved your problem, *you're telling me I should have done something differently*.  Honestly, I really don't get it.  In any case, don't expect help from me in the future.

Comment: You attacked what i wrote as being wrong, and yet were able to simply get the answer with out more information. I put everything you needed up. You were just being a dick, honestly. Kudos for answering it. I awarded you the points. This is my real complaint with stackoverflow.. if a question isn't something they can google, most people just complain not enough information. You had no problem finding the answer with what i gave you but you said not enough info. You were wrong.

Comment: @user1202909: you still don't get it.  When people ask for clarifications, they're trying to help you faster and more accurately.  There are a million things that can go wrong.  You could have been using an old version of the library with up-to-date documentation, in which case your code could have been fine and simple "upgrade to the next version" would have been the right answer.  My point is that without clarifications, I had to guess.  Remember that my initial answer was wrong and you asked me to check again based on new information (working samples using getenv()).

Comment: @user1202909: Note that your first comment to this answer is one of the things that led me to find the real answer.  The tutorial you referenced uses `FCGI_Accept`, not `FCGX_Accept_r`.  I then checked the documentation of both functions to look at the differences, and the answer happened to be in the documentation for `FCGX_Accept_r`.  I probably would not have noticed this otherwise.   I really don't understand your reluctance to help people help you.  Answering a question can't always be done with a single round-trip and might require some discussion.

Comment: @user1202909: And please, point me out anything I've said that was rude or impolite, or otherwise could be interpreted as "being a dick".  I insited on helping you even when you didn't want to help yourself.  How is that being a dick?

Comment: @user1202909: The `const` in there means you can't modify the string contents, not that you can't change the pointer. Also, you can declare this variable inside the loop like `for(...){const char* query_string=...;}`, in which case, you'll get a new "constant" variable at each iteration.